# Add 2 new columns to existing dataframe using apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I want to use the apply function that:
- Takes 2 columns as inputs - Outputs two new columns based on a function.

An example is with this add_multiply function.

```py
#function with 2 column inputs and 2 outputs
def add_multiply (a,b):
  return (a+b, a*b )

#example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})

#this doesn't work
df[['add', 'multiply']] = df.apply(lambda x: add_multiply(x['col1'], x['col2']), axis=1)
```

ideal result:

```py
col1  col2  add  multiply
1     3     4    3
2     4     6    8
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add `result_type='expand'` in the `apply`:

> ‘expand’ : list-like results will be turned into columns.

```
df[['add', 'multiply']]=df.apply(lambda x: add_multiply(x['col1'], x['col2']),axis=1,
                             result_type='expand')
```

Or call a dataframe constructor:

```
df[['add', 'multiply']]=pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x: add_multiply(x['col1'], 
                                    x['col2']), axis=1).tolist())
```

---

```
   col1  col2  add  multiply
0     1     3    4         3
1     2     4    6         8
```

Comment: this won't work if the dataframe is empty.

Answer (score 9):

anky_91's answer highlights a useful option in `apply`.

For this particular case however, `apply` is not even required,

```
df['add'], df['multiply'] = add_multiply(df['col1'],df['col2'])
```

This works because add_multiply just returns a tuple with 2 series `(df.col1 + df.col2, df.col1 * df.col2)`, which use pandas-native vectorized `+` and `*`. There is no need for iteration which is when you would need to use `apply`.