# modifying 2 columns based on a condition in a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df with 5 columns where aa is the sum of (ww+zz) :

```
     xx    yy    ww   zz  aa
A    5     3     4    2   6  
B    2     0     4    1   5
C    3     0     4    2   6
D    3     2     3    3   6
```

I am looking forward that whenever the yy column has a value of 0, then add the value of zz into ww, ww set it to zero  and if the value of zz is different from zero, leave it as it is.

The desired output would be:

```
     xx    yy    ww   zz  aa
A    5     3     4    2   6  
B    2     0     5    0   5
C    3     0     6    0   6  
D    3     2     3    3   6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
df[['ww', 'zz']] = (
    df.apply(lambda x: [x.zz+x.ww, 0] if x.yy==0 else [x.ww, x.zz], axis=1)
    .apply(pd.Series)
)

    xx  yy  ww  zz  aa
A   5   3   4   2   6
B   2   0   5   0   5
C   3   0   6   0   6
D   3   2   3   3   6
```

If performance is a concern, use this version:

```
(
    df.assign(y=df.yy.eq(0))
    .assign(ww=lambda x: x.zz.mul(x.y).add(x.ww))
    .assign(zz=lambda x: x.zz.mul(~x.y))
    .drop('y', axis=1)
)
```

Comment: Although this works, `apply(pd.Series)` is something you do not want to do, since its teribbly slow.

Comment: Also, the first approach could be written as `df[['ww', 'zz']] = df.apply(lambda x: [x.zz+x.ww, 0] if x.yy==0 else [x.ww, x.zz], axis=1,result_type='expand')`. See anky_91's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646384/add-2-new-columns-to-existing-dataframe-using-apply/57646615#57646615

Comment: Thanks @Erfan, just added a faster version if performance is a concern.

Comment: @MarkWang, thanks and I never used that parameter. Good to learn something new everyday :-)

Comment: using `lambda` twice will not be any more perfomant. There are vectorized answers here, OP is probably not aware.

Comment: @Erfan, in the second solution, the apply is column wise and it's thousands faster than the 1st solution. Performance is similar to your solution.

Comment: Still `2.3` times slower than the vectorized solution. See timings in my answer. `apply lambda x` will never be faster than the optimized solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Create a mask identifying the rows with `yy` column eq to `0` and use `where` to apply the condition.

```
mask_0 = df['yy'].eq(0)

df['ww'] = df['zz'].where(mask_0,0) + df['ww']

df['zz'] = df['zz'].where(~mask_0,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to conditionally add `zz` to `ww` and [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) to replace the values in `zz` with `0` if `yy == 0`:

```
m = df['yy'].eq(0)

df['ww'] = np.where(m, df['ww'].add(df['zz']), df['ww'])
df['zz'] = df['zz'].mask(m, 0)
```

**Output**

```
   xx  yy  ww  zz  aa
0   5   3   4   2   6
1   2   0   5   0   5
2   3   0   6   0   6
3   3   2   3   3   6
```

---

**Timing test**

```
df = pd.concat([df]*200000, ignore_index=True)
```

*Erfan*

```
%%timeit

m = df['yy'].eq(0)

df['ww'] = np.where(m, df['ww'].add(df['zz']), df['ww'])
df['zz'] = df['zz'].mask(m, 0)

13.8 ms ± 112 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

*Allen*

```
%%timeit

(
    df.assign(y=df.yy.eq(0))
    .assign(ww=lambda x: x.zz.mul(x.y).add(x.ww))
    .assign(zz=lambda x: x.zz.mul(~x.y))
    .drop('y', axis=1)
)


31.3 ms ± 2.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(data={"xx": [5,2,3,3], "yy": [3,0,0,2], "ww": [4,4,4,3], "zz": [2,1,2,3], "aa": [6,5,6,6]}, index=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
>>> df["ww"][df["yy"]==0]=df["ww"]+df["zz"]
>>> df["zz"][df["yy"]==0]=0
>>> df
   xx  yy  ww  zz  aa
A   5   3   4   2   6
B   2   0   5   0   5
C   3   0   6   0   6
D   3   2   3   3   6
```