# Create 2 or more columns from function's output in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, valueerror

I'm trying to create two columns for a data frame from a function that returns a tuple
I have an existing dataframe named df and I'm using apply lambda to calulate 2 values based upon 2 columns of my data frame

```
def f(a,b):
    return a+b, a-b
```

```
df['SUM'], df['DIFF'] = apply(lambda x: f(x.COLUMN_1,x.COLUMN_2)
```

but I'm getting the error:

**ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)**

My function returns a series of tuples whith the same number of rows as df

Comment: where is the dataset? [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)..

Comment: Your code actually works for me. Edit: not anymore since your edit

Comment: It works if `a` and `b` are Series, because then the return is a tuple of Series and each is set to the column you specify; i.e. `df = pd.DataFrame(data=range(10)); df['SUM'], df['DIFF'] = f(df[0], df[0])`

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680191/remove-opening-and-closing-parenthesis-with-word-in-pandas/58680226#58680226

Comment: Also does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646384/add-2-new-columns-to-existing-dataframe-using-apply/57646426#57646426

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,2], 'b': [3,4,5]})

df[['SUM','DIFF']] = df[['a','b']].apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'SUM': x['a']+x['b'], 'DIFF': x['a']-x['b']}), axis=1)
```

Yields:

```
   a  b  SUM  DIFF
0  0  3    3    -3
1  1  4    5    -3
2  2  5    7    -3
```

Comment: Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i do it, i create a column with the tuple and then split it, here's some code i used before on another post that should help:

```
def return_tuple(x):
    if x in [1,'1','one']: 
        return (1, 'one')
    else:
        return (2, 'two')

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3]})
df['test'] = df['col1'].apply(return_tuple)

df
#   col1      test
#0     1  (1, one)
#1     2  (2, two)
#2     3  (2, two)

df[['test','test2']] = pd.DataFrame(df['test'].to_list(), index=df.index)

df

#   col1  test test2
#0     1     1   one
#1     2     2   two
#2     3     2   two
```